# Repository not found

Tags: git, github, repository

I am following the steps mentioned in the https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ to create a remote repository and push the data in my local directory to remote.

I have 2 queries?

1. Do I need to create a remote repository manually on GitHub or will it be created automatically after following the steps. I followed the steps but I don't see any repository created and when I push the data using git push command, after entering the login details I got the error repository not created.
2. And when I reuse  the git remote command, I get the error repository already exists.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've literally run the command exactly as below:

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
```

They don't meant to run the command like that. I imagine if you ran the command `'git remote -v'` you'd have something that looked like this:

```
origin  remote repository URL (fetch)
origin  remote repository URL (push)
```

What they actually want you to do is to take your repository url and put it in here. So for step 7, you need to go to wherever your repository is stored, I'm assuming on github, and get that repo url. It will look something like:

```
yourUsername@github.com:yourRepo.git for ssh
https://github.com/yourRepo.git for https
```

Take your repo url and re-run the add origin command like this:

```
git remote add origin yourUsername@github.com:yourRepo.git
```

Your issue is your remote is incorrectly setup.

Comment: I have not created any repository on GitHub site.  Also I am using the remote repository URL and not literally running and I can see the URL as well using git remote -v.

Comment: You will need a repository location. Please post the output from git remote -v

Comment: origin  https://github.com/nitinvijay23/lregression.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/nitinvijay23/lregression.git (push) 

I don't understand even after the origin is created I am unable to push the data to git.